# Howto save an array into a "field" with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save a list of #Hashtags into my Schema.
Each document in the database has different #Hashtags.

What is the easiest implementation using mongoose and node.js? Do I really need to work with an additional schema for the #Hashtags? Or can I save an array into a field?

Comment: Shortest answer : yes you can! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using mongoose you can define hashtags field like this: `hashTags: [String]`.

Now you can use hashTags like a plain JavaScript array.

Also support for arrays is builtin in MongoDB, so if you want a little more advanced features you can refer to [MongoDB Array Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update-array/).